# how to get process name of loaded process in QT

Tags: qt, qt4

i have written QT dll which is loaded by a process. how can i get the process name in Dll using QT api's ?

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QCoreApplication::applicationName()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop) should do what you want.

Comment: I am not sure a DLL has access to the global/static QCoreApplication instance. The process may not be a Qt app.

Comment: if the host application(Non QT) loaded the QT dll , then is it possble to get the applicaion name in the DLL ?